# Get real path of a file in a Java class

Tags: java, path, filepath

I get a file like that :

```
String myFile = "D:/dev/workspace/MyProject/WebContent/stats/stats.csv";
File statsFile = new File(myFile);
```

But I want to only have the relative path as `stats/stats.csv`. I don't want to have to write the complete path in my code.

In a servlet, I do it this way :

```
File statsFile = new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "stats/stats.csv");
```

But here it is not in a servlet. So what is the equivalent way in a java class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put it in the CLASSPATH and read it from an `InputStream` acquired using `getResourceAsStream()` .  It's the path-independent way to access a file.

Comment: He says he doesn't want to use it in a Servlet

Comment: One could get it through `SomeApplicationClass.class.getResourceAsStream()`

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how it works. I do this : `this.class.getResourceAsStream("stats/stats.csv")` but I can guess it is wrong.

Comment: The means that the parent of the "stats" folder has to be in your CLASSPATH.  If it returns a null InputStream, it means you did it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
String basePath = "D:/dev/workspace/MyProject/WebContent";
String absolutePath = "D:/dev/workspace/MyProject/WebContent/stats/stats.csv";

String relativePath = new File(basePath).toURI().
                        relativize(new File(absolutePath).toURI()).getPath();

System.out.println(relativePath);   // stats/stats.csv
```

`basePath` is the path, relative to which you want to get `Relative Path`.

Comment: In fact, I search a way to find `basePath` without writing it.

Comment: @Jim.. Then your work is still reduced.. I also faced the same problem while working on one of my project.. then only I found out that I can do this..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
I can use my JSP to use `File statsFile = new File(this.getServletContext().getRealPath("/") + "stats/stats.csv")` and then pass `statsFile` to my class.